# Can DisplayPort™ over USB-C™ communicate successfully with an HDMI Type A port?

Tags: hdmi, displayport, usb-c

I have an Acer Chromebook with a DisplayPort™-enabled USB-C™ port, have it connected via an adapter cable to an HDMI port on a 2019 HiSense TV, use it routinely to play various Zoom and YouTube video streams from tabs in Chrome--no problems.

But last night, I plugged the same Chromebook via the same adapter cable into an HDMI Type A port on an older Panasonic TV, tried to play a FB Live concert in a Chrome tab. The audio played fine on the TV speaker, but the TV screen showed my Chromebook desktop wallpaper, even though the Chromebook itself was playing the video as it should.

Does anybody have a fix, or is there none?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you've set the Chromebook to "Extend desktop" mode instead of the mirroring mode.

> On your Chromebook, click the status area at the bottom-right corner of the screen and select the connected external screen.
>
> https://www.howtogeek.com/262282/how-to-connect-an-external-monitor-to-a-chromebook/